# Android exe linking system shared object (.so file) as local shared object (.so file)

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have now wasted two days on this. Any pointers in resolving the issue would really be helpfull. 
My Android.mk file is as below.
The issue is that libst.so should link as a system so with my executable opti.
But when i open the execuatble in an Hex it lists the complete path to the so file libst.so. While the other dependent so files are listed correctly.
This results in CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE error finally since the so file is being searched in the local path 
e.g.

/media/ExtHDD/NIEL/OPTI/TEST/optimize/workspace/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libst.so" not found
rather than searching for inside
/system/lib/libst.so where it should ideally look for.

Any pointers or suggestions will be of great help. Thanks.

```
  LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    SRC_PATH := ${LOCAL_PATH}/../../..

    LOCAL_MODULE := libsmp
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libs_beta/armeabi-v7a/libsmp.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
    LOCAL_MODULE := libocv
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libs_beta/armeabi-v7a/libOCv.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := libst 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libs_beta/armeabi-v7a/libst.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := opti
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(SRC_PATH)/main.cpp \

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
        $(SRC_PATH) \
        $(SRC_PATH)/util \
        $(SRC_PATH)/src \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include_beta \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include_beta/opencv \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include_beta/opencv2


    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libc libsmp libocv libst 
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -fopenmp -fpermissive -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -flax-vector-conversions
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib

    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
    LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie

    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: The Hex editor shows my exe as follows

libsmp.so.libOCv.so./media/ExtHDD/NIEL/OPTI/TEST/optimize/workspace/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libst.so.liblog.so.libstdc++.so.libm.so.libc.so.libdl.so
As you can see the libst.so has a complete path to it. whereas it should appear like the other so files

Comment: This is commanded by the way libsmp.so was linked.

Comment: @AlexCohn I am not sure what you are suggesting. All the other so files are appearing correctly. I have stripped down the makefile here but even if i remove libsmp.so and just include libst.so i get the same result

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo on my side. I mean, the full path is result of how the prebuilt **libst.so** was linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that so files which have some dependency between them cannot be resolved using android-ndk build. In this case when i got the project under the android source tree and built it exe was correctly generated.
I also had to change the mk file from the above as below everything worked fine.

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libst
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
#32 bit
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_$(TARGET_2ND_ARCH) := lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE)$(LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```